# how to use readonly in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc

```
//controller
     @RequestMapping("/view")
         public String viewEmpDetails(@RequestParam int emp_Id,@ModelAttribute Employee emp,Model model){
             emp=empService.getEmpDetails(emp_Id);
             model.addAttribute("isView",true);
             model.addAttribute("emp",emp);
             model.addAttribute("readonly", true);
             model.addAttribute("action","/getList");
              return "employee";
         }
//jsp page
     <td>First Name <span style="color:red;">*</span>:</td>  
      <td><form:input id="firstName" path="firstName" value="${emp.firstName}" readonly="true" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="firstNameError" style="visibility:hidden;color:red"></td>  
     </tr>  
     <tr>  
      <td>Last Name :</td>  
      <td><form:input id="lastName" path="lastName" value="${emp.lastName}" readonly="true" /></td>  
       <td><input type="text" id="lastNameError" style="visibility:hidden;color:red"></td>
     </tr>
```

i am using only 1 jsp to perform view,delete nd edit operation.How to disable the text boxes when i click on view.Please give the solution.

Comment: Please check the below example and let know if you find any issue.
And one more point don't use form:input tag it little difficult to use. Go with simple html <input type="text"/> tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's :

```
$('#seclector_id').prop('disabled', true);
```

or

```
$('#seclector_id').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

By checking your model attribute in jsp:

```
model.addAttribute("readonly", true);
```

Just add below line in your jsp page and perform check operations given in the jsFiddle example:

```
<input type="hidden" id="conditionCheck" value="${readonly}"/>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mahajanankur/xvqddma6/)

I hope this will work.